# Felix lists OSGI Bundle as Active but Gogo Shell Command Not accessible (dependency related)

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, ipojo

This basic code succeeds at making the command scopeA:test accessible in the shell:

```
package com.A;

import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Instantiate;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Provides;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Requires;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.ServiceProperty;
import org.apache.felix.service.command.Descriptor;

@Component(immediate = true)
@Instantiate
@Provides(specifications = Commands.class)
public final class Commands {

    @ServiceProperty(name = "osgi.command.scope", value = "scopeA")
    String scope;

    @ServiceProperty(name = "osgi.command.function", value = "{}")
    String[] function = new String[] {
            "test"
    };

    @Descriptor("Example")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

However, if I add a constructor that depends on another OSGI component, it the command is no longer accessible and "help" doesn't list it. Yet the bundle can still be loading into an active state.

```
package com.A;

import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Instantiate;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Provides;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Requires;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.ServiceProperty;
import org.apache.felix.service.command.Descriptor;

import com.B;

@Component(immediate = true)
@Instantiate
@Provides(specifications = Commands.class)
public final class Commands {

    public Commands(@Requires B b) {
    }

    @ServiceProperty(name = "osgi.command.scope", value = "scopeA")
    String scope;

    @ServiceProperty(name = "osgi.command.function", value = "{}")
    String[] function = new String[] {
            "test"
    };

    @Descriptor("Example")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

The contents of B is simply:

```
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Instantiate;
import org.apache.felix.ipojo.annotations.Provides;

@Component(immediate = true)
@Instantiate
@Provides
final class B {
}
```

Any ideas why the command is no longer listed? Tips to find more information on the state so that I can better debug this?

Comment: Is the B service actually published? You can check with the command `inspect cap service [id]` where [id] should be the ID of the bundle containing component B.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that commands needs the @Requires to be on a field rather than in the constructor.

```
@Requires
B b;
```

The constructor also must be removed.

This is because gogo has a special method of invoking the component.

Answer (score 0):

also for me this needs to be changed

```
@ServiceProperty(name = "osgi.command.function", value = "{}")
String[] function = new String[] {
    "test"
};
```

to

```
@ServiceProperty(name = "osgi.command.function", value = "{test}")
String[] function;
```